# Nested absolute operations

Tags: absolute-value

The question is: are the following two functions equivalent? And if yes, what properties of the absolute value should I use to prove it?

$f_1(x,y,z)$ = $|\, x + |y+z| \,|$

$f_2(x,y,z)$ = $| \,|x+y| + z \,|$

Comment: Consider $f_1(1,0,-1)$ and $f_2(1,0,-1)$.

Comment: Great! It means the functions are not equivalent: 

f1(1,0,−1) = 2; f2(1,0,−1) = 0

Is there any way to proof it using properties of the absolute value?

Comment: Try x = -z and y = 0.